# mb_detect_encoding returns both ASCII and UTF8

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I'm getting some data from a MySQL database that has charset utf8mb4 set (both for tables and fields).

I also set the charset upon connection by

```
$conn->set_charset("utf8mb4");
```

When I run mb_detect_encoding(), most strings returns as ASCII, but string with special characters (like interpunct/middle dot) returns as UTF-8. Is this correct, or should they all be UTF-8? Any ideas why they aren't?

Comment: Depends on the mb_detect_order().... if UTF-8 comes before ASCII, then they should all be detected as UTF-8

Comment: UTF-8 and ASCII are the same when the first 7 bits are the same.  This is the first 127 characters (128 if you count `\0`), which are standard ASCII.

Comment: @GordonLinoff So this seems normal?

Comment: @janlindso . . . It can be tricky to auto-detect the encoding.  ASCII-7 is a subset of UTF-8.

Comment: Why would you attempt to detect (guess; determine a list of candidates) an encoding when you already know which one is being used? Tip: Be sure to pass that knowledge on to whomever you send the text to, too, so they don't have to guess either. Perhaps you'll do that through the HTTP Content-Type header and/or HTML meta charset tag.